# Creating optional multiple buttons for jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

So I know to create multiple buttons with jQuery UI you simply do:

```
buttons : [{
    text  : settings.buttonText,
    click : function () { settings.buttonFunction(); }
},
{
    text  : button2Text,
    click : function () { settings.button2Function(); }
}
}]
```

I have a plugin I've created to handle & make dialogboxes similar site-wide, and recently need to add the option of passing in multiple buttons, not just 1.

Now typically this whole section doesn't even get run unless a button is even wanted. I have a quick `if (settings.buttonText) { }` wrapped around it. But the problem is even though I don't pass in button2Text etc, the button is still appearing. Besides doing some newbish thing like `.hide()`...

My question is: **How can i have that second `{ text ... click ... }` area be dynamic and only appear in the object if settings.button2Text is passed into the plugin**? Is this even possible?

I feel like the solution is so simple I'm just braindead right now :) Thanks for any input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do the logic before you actually set that up. Something like this:

```
var myButtons = [{
  text  : settings.buttonText,
  click : function () { settings.buttonFunction(); }
}];

if (addSecondButton) {
  myButtons.push({
    text  : button2Text,
    click : function () { settings.button2Function(); }
  });
}
```

Then you can launch the dialog like this:

```
$(foo).dialog({buttons: myButtons})
```